# Can a teleportation circle be made in the air?

Tags: dnd-4e, teleportation

Here's the situation: A fire titan on his own demi-plane sent the party on a side quest to retrieve something for him and gave them the rune combination for a teleportation circle that would get them back to his throne room. I want the titan to betray them by having the circle resolve in mid air over a pit of lava so they would fall towards it.

The Create Teleportation Circle ritual will probably be the basis for creating the circle, and the players will probably use Planar Portal to get there. But the reason it's a little tricky for me is that we're in the Elemental Chaos here and I can reasonably assume that the titan can more or less will whatever the hell he wants in the demi-plane, so I don't know how constrained I necessarily am to the Create Teleportation Circle ritual.

Is there anything in the rules that would prevent me from doing this? Must a teleportation circle resolve on a surface instead of mid-air?

Comment: remember that in 4e you're not by any means limited by "What the players can do" as far as plot/monster abilities goes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having teleportation circles in midair is plausible. The players might not be able to do it themselves, but don't let that stop you from creating ones for Plot.

The 4e books aren't 100% clear on what a teleportation circle *is,* beyond a bunch of writing in a ring. From the Manual of the Planes, p19:

> A teleportation circle is a ring of sigils and glyphs inscribed or chiseled around the area where a ritually created portal will appear.

But, probably, if you're a powerful NPC like a Fire Titan, you have some secret ritual to inscribe glowy runes in midair with magic.

The *Create Teleportation Circle* ritual from MoP also refers to inscribing stuff on a surface, but only in the flavour text, which 4e has generally always been super flexible about and only provided as suggestions. The actual *rules text* of the ritual just cares that you create magic sigils somehow. Again, a Fire Titan could probably do this for plot reasons.

Just be aware that if your players are trying to get there via Linked or Planar Portal, they'll be able to see the immediate 60-foot surroundings of the portal before they dive through, and might be concerned about all the red light and black smoke, depending.

Comment: Damn, I keep forgetting about the ability to see the surrounding area. They'll probably notice the lack of floor. And I suppose it's super railroad-y to say the titan can just create the illusion of safety.

Maybe I'll just have it resolve on a fake floor and then have the trap trigger or something.

Comment: @Avidan Don't bother with fake safety, make it real safety...in a 60 foot radius. Then drop said 60-foot radius room into a massive lake of lava. This also has the benefit of giving the players a few panicked minutes to run around trying to figure out how to escape the throne room replica while it slowly sinks into the lava.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your goal is to avoid breaking the RAW here to ensure that players don't complain or feel cheated. You could easily have the Fire Titan inscribe these runes on a ring of stone which is then magically suspended from above the lava pit.

A simple hallucinatory terrain spell takes care of the party seeing the area around the portal as well, but may be beyond the abilities of your fire titan.